# Android how to set ScrollBar in Edittext?

Tags: android

I want to ScrollText in Edittext and also show Scrollbar at corner. I Scroll the text By Using

```
questionEntry.setScroller(new Scroller(myContext)); 
questionEntry.setMaxLines(1); 
questionEntry.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
questionEntry.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Scrolling text works,  but the ScrollBar isn't visible. How can I make it visible?

Answer (score 27):

This may help you.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edt_task_disc" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:gravity="top"
                      android:background="@drawable/text_aerea" 
                      android:hint="Task Discription"
                      android:textSize="15sp" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                      android:maxHeight="35dp"
                      android:scrollbars="vertical"
                      />
```

Please add `android:scrollbars="vertical"` to your xml code of edit text, and it will work fine.

Answer (score 8):

> Only sample
>
> In Your Java file

```
 EditText dwEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DwEdit);

 dwEdit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (view.getId() ==R.id.DwEdit) {
                        view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        switch (event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

> And in your Xml file ...

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/DwEdit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"

        android:minLines="10"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences">
        </EditText>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have checked too options but i think

```
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

this is best or you can do it by defining multiline

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

or also you can solve this issue by

```
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }

            return false;
       }

  });
```